# Can't find a helmet that's large enough please help!

Tags: helmets

I have tried the largest helmet I can find the bern 2xl 3xl wont fit.
The problem I am having is the width of the helmets are not wide enough.
I have a big head.

Comment: I'm sorry but we don't give product recommendations. They tend to be very opinion-based, depend on regional availability and quickly go out of date. Different manufacturers do tend to have different fits: when I was trying on helmets, all the styles offered by one particular brand had a size that fit me well, whereas none of another brand did, in any size. I think the only advice we can give is to go to different bike shops and try out different brands.

Comment: I have the same problem - your best bet is to go to a LBS and try some on.  Just like shoes, buying online is not going to work for you.

Comment: I can quote Criggie. For me even purchasing a baseball hat is a challenge, but a visit to a LBS allowed me to find a solution

Comment: Not all helmets are born alike. One brand make wider helmets while another makes longer ones, for the same size. So you'll have to shop around and try on different makes to find one that has more room from ear to ear and where the circumference of the head can be adjusted enough for the general fit.

Comment: Be aware that your haircut can affect your helmet fit.  Mine's loose when recently trimmed, and when helmet is uncomfortable, it is time for another chop.

Answer (score 2):

Helmets.org is a nonprofit organization that compiles lists of helmets that fit specific needs, including a [list of helmets that fit particularly large heads](https://helmets.org/bighead.htm). Their website ToS bars verbatim copying (even though data like that is probably not protectable), so all I can do here is link.